# How to send a Bulk email to different email ID's

Tags: java

I want to test my Emil Com server and SMTP capacity. So i need to send mail to different Email account from my Application. But i cant not create 10000 mail iD's each time. IS there any simulation tool available to send a Email from my application without creating the Mail id's (Gmail, yahoo etc)

Answer (score 0):

> Use this method `emailNotification()` and implement as per your need. Concatinate all the `email_id` with a comma seprator `abc@abc.com,abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com` and pass the string to the v_sBCC.

This function might help you out. Thanks..

```
 private void emailNotification(){
            String v_sTo;
            String v_sFrom;
            String v_sBCC = "abc@gmail.com,abc1@gmail.com" //add a number of emails with a Comma separator.
            DataSource v_objSource;
            Properties v_objProperties;
            Session v_objSession;
            MimeMessage v_sMessage;
            BodyPart v_objMessageBodyPart;
            Multipart v_objMultipart;
            try {
                v_sFrom = "Set From Name To Show User that From which Email you received Mail";
                v_objProperties = new Properties();
                v_objProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp.google.com);  
                v_objProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
                v_objProperties.put("mail.debug", "false");  
                v_objProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);  
                v_objProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 25);  
                v_objProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                v_objProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
                v_objSession = Session.getInstance(v_objProperties, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("gmail.id", "password");
                    }
                });
                v_sMessage = new MimeMessage(v_objSession);
                v_sMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(v_sFrom, "Your Company Name"));
                v_sMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(v_sTo));
                v_sMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(v_sBCC));
                v_sMessage.setSubject("Set Your Own Subject");
                v_sMessage.setText("Set Your Own Body");
                Transport.send(v_sMessage); 
            } catch (MessagingException v_exException) {
                v_exException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException v_exException) {
                v_exException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```